# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

Hello guys a have a problem importing my css file, the error is

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/css/component/footer.css'**

Im trying to fix it with question on internet but I can't, could you help me?

Thanks a lot

this is my Footer.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

import logo from '../../assets/images/footer-logo.png';

import '../assets/css/component/footer.css';

const Footer = () => {
  return (
 <div className='footer-top'>
    <div className='auto-container'>
        <div className='top-inner clearfix'>

            <div className='footer-logo pull-left'>
                <div className='bg-color'>
                    <figure className='logo'>
                        <a href="index.js">
                            <img src={logo} alt='Logo' />
                        </a>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='footer-into pull right'>
                <ul className='info-list clearfix'>
                    <li>
                        <i className='flaticon-email'></i>
                        <span>Email Address</span>
                        <h6>
                            <a href="mailto:pressureking007@gmail.com">pressureking007@gmail.com</a>
                        </h6>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i className='flaticon-telephone'></i>
                        <span>We are located at</span>
                        <h6>Tampa, Florida</h6>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i className='flaticon-pin'></i>
                        <span>Phone Line</span>
                        <h6>
                            <a href="tel:8137705290">813-770-5290</a>
                        </h6>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>  )
}

export default Footer
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "afirstchoicetampa",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

If you need more data just ask me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to import assets from the `public` folder - but you can only import from `src` or one of its subfolders. So if you put your image in the same folder as the Footer code, you can

```js
import logo from './footer-logo.png';
```

Comment: Im trying to get the CSS file, the image one I got it.